# Typescript target es6 and es2015

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Could anyone explain what exactly is the difference between `target: es6` and `target: es2015` in typescript? Couldn't really find anything on this.

Comment: It would be weird if they did different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5272), they are synonymous.